# Build WAR and self-executable JAR from Java web project

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a Java servlets project and I want to build a WAR to deploy to a server and an executable JAR with an embedded Jetty server that can run standalone.
The project looks like this:

```
HelloWorldServlets
  common
    src/main
      java
        HelloServlet.java
      webapp
        index.jsp
    build.gradle
  jetty
    src/main
      java
        JettyServer.java
    build.gradle
  build.gradle
```

`jetty` imports `common` as compile dependency. The build task is:

```
jar {
  manifest { attributes "Main-Class": "JettyServer" }
  from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) })
}
```

`jar` task in `common` is as follows:

```
jar {
  sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs += ["src/main/webapp"]
}
```

The web resources are included `common.jar` and `common.jar` is flattened inside `jetty.jar`, so `jetty.jar` has the resources in its root, however setting the server as:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
server.setHandler(context);

context.setResourceBase("/");
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(Hello.class, "");
```

always results in **HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /index.jsp.**

Should I not flatten `common.jar` into `jetty.jar` or I am missing something about the `ResourceBase`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things of note in your code example.

- Since you are expecting to use JSP, you have to satisfy the minimum requirements that JSP has.
- The `setResourceBase(String)` must be an absolute path and/or URI reference (no relative paths) (JSP requirement)
- The DefaultServlet must be defined properly. (JSP requirement)
- When adding Servlets (or Filters), you must use a valid url-pattern. (Servlet requirement)
- Add the `DefaultHandler` last in your handler tree, as it will help when you have context and/or handler errors to troubleshoot.

The most common reason for your issues are that using the `WebAppContext` causes the standard Servlet classloader isolation to be enforced, and is likely causing your problems.

Either break the classloader ...

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);

// Figure out what path to serve content from
ClassLoader cl = DemoProject.class.getClassLoader();
// We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
// designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
URL f = cl.getResource("jsp-root/index.jsp");
if (f == null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
}

// Resolve file to directory
URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
System.err.println("WebRoot is " + webRootUri);

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(Hello.class, "/hello");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true); // use server classloader first

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(context);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // for errors when request doesn't match above handlers
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

... or just don't use a WebAppContext ...

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);

// Figure out what path to serve content from
ClassLoader cl = DemoProject.class.getClassLoader();
// We look for a file, as ClassLoader.getResource() is not
// designed to look for directories (we resolve the directory later)
URL f = cl.getResource("jsp-root/index.jsp");
if (f == null)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find resource directory");
}

// Resolve file to directory
URI webRootUri = f.toURI().resolve("./").normalize();
System.err.println("WebRoot is " + webRootUri);

ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(webRootUri));
context.setContextPath("/");
context.addServlet(Hello.class, "/hello");

// Must be added last, must be named "default" (JSP and Servlet requirement)
ServletHolder holderDef = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
holderDef.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","false");
context.addServlet(holderDef,"/"); // Using "default" url-pattern (JSP and Servlet requirement)

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(context);
handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler()); // for errors when request doesn't match above handlers
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

but be aware, you have more work to do in order to enable JSP on `ServletContextHandler`.

For details, see: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp